# How can I get String values rather than integer

Tags: vb.net

## How To get StartString And EndString

```
 Dim startNumber As Integer
    Dim endNumber As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    startNumber = 1
    endNumber = 4

    For i = startNumber To endNumber

        MsgBox(i)

    Next i
```

Output: 1,2,3,4
I want mo make this like sample: startString AAA  endString AAD
and the output is AAA, AAB, AAC, AAD

Comment: Strings don't increment like that. You would need to make a custom function and set the limits of each place value. It wouldn't be too hard to do.

Comment: Can You give me guys how can I perform that in two textbox. example textbox 1 = AAA and textbox 2 = AAD output is  AAA, AAB, AAC, AAD

Comment: Why are you wanting to enter the initial "AA"? Is it just a prefix or are you expecting to be able to loop through "AAA" to "ZZZ", for example?

Comment: No it is just an example, In my Case My client wants to scan two serial number lets call them fromtthisserailnumber and tothisserialnumber. If the user input the starting serial example S30AB to S30B1 it will get the values between them, and every ok in messagebox it will insert to my database.

Comment: @user3795723 - Then you need to define what makes the valid set of codes that can be generated. So, for example `S30AZ` is valid and the next value is `S30A0`, and then `S30A9` is followed by `S30BA`. Or is `S30A%`, `S30B#`, or `S30B®` valid?

Comment: @user3795723 - Or another way of looking at it is what are the valid characters per position? Or is it a uniform alphabet?

Comment: in this case the better solution is to store it into a database sort it and filter from db too.Much faster and with a simple query you may filter all what you need. S30AD to S30B1 is not a logic sequence.better stuff is use database in example SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE COLUMNAME BETWEEN 'VALU1' AND VALUE'2' .It assume that table as previously orderby columname asc or desc in order to be sure that order is the correct one

Comment: Yeah I know that Select statement, but what if in my case I want To store that select statement into insert. I want to insert values between two data but how can I don that in query because in my research there is no where clause in insert

Comment: are this barcode unique right .....so i suppose that you have an index into database.It will thrown an exception if you will duplicate the index key too.Take care of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple function that should be easy to understand and use. Every time you call it, it just increments the string by one value. Just be careful to check the values in the text boxes or you can have an endless loop on your hands.

```
Function AddOneChar(Str As String) As String
    AddOneChar = ""
    Str = StrReverse(Str)
    Dim CharSet As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    Dim Done As Boolean = False
    For Each Ltr In Str
        If Not Done Then
            If InStr(CharSet, Ltr) = CharSet.Length Then
                Ltr = CharSet(0)
            Else
                Ltr = CharSet(InStr(CharSet, Ltr))
                Done = True
            End If
        End If
        AddOneChar = Ltr & AddOneChar
    Next
    If Not Done Then
        AddOneChar = CharSet(0) & AddOneChar
    End If
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim S = TextBox1.Text
    Do Until S = TextBox2.Text
        S = AddOneChar(S)
        MsgBox(S)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Your Code is Very understanding and correct in my problem, but I think in these part there is something wrong, Do Until S = TextBox2.Text It never stops

Comment: You have to make sure the larger number goes into the second box.

Comment: This one is better but it never stop, If I Input AAA TO AAD the output is AAA...AAD..AAZ..AA0..AAA9 it should be AAA AAAB AAC AAD.

Comment: The function AddOneChar is doing the work, you need to compare the output to make it stop. I tested this and it does stop. TextBox1.Text = AAA and TextBox2.Text = AAD gives me AAB, AAC, AAD. If you add an additional MsgBox above the Do, you can show AAA as well. Please check your TextBox1 and TextBox2 values.

Comment: It only works on the last character but what if in the middle example AAA to A9A the output should be AAA...AZA..A0A..A9A

Comment: one last question sir, every click ok it will insert to my database How can I do that? this is my query to insert it to my table.  cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO tblscandata(barcode) VALUES (" S ", con).

Comment: That depends on what database you are using. It might be best to start another question with the correct tags for the database.

Answer (score 1):

This works as a way to all the codes given an arbitrary alphabet:

```
Public Function Generate(starting As String, ending As String, alphabet As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Dim increment As Func(Of String, String) = _
        Function(x)
            Dim f As Func(Of IEnumerable(Of Char), IEnumerable(Of Char)) = Nothing
            f = _
                Function(cs)
                    If cs.Any() Then
                        Dim first = cs.First()
                        Dim rest = cs.Skip(1)
                        If first = alphabet.Last() Then
                            rest = f(rest)
                            first = alphabet(0)
                        Else
                            first = alphabet(alphabet.IndexOf(first) + 1)
                        End If
                        Return Enumerable.Repeat(first, 1).Concat(rest)
                    Else
                        Return Enumerable.Empty(Of Char)()
                    End If
                End Function
            Return New String(f(x.ToCharArray().Reverse()).Reverse().ToArray())
        End Function
    Dim results = New List(Of String)
    Dim text = starting
    While True
        results.Add(text)
        If text = ending Then
            Exit While
        End If
        text = increment(text)
    End While
    Return results
End Function
```

I used it like this to produce the required result:

```
Dim alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"

Dim results = Generate("S30AB", "S30B1", alphabet)
```

This gave me 63 values:

```
S30AB 
S30AC 
...
S30BY 
S30BZ 
S30B0 
S30B1
```

It should now be very easy to modify the alphabet as needed and to use the results.

Comment: I copy paste your code there so many blue error end statement

Comment: @user3795723 - It worked fine in LinqPad. Maybe it's to do with the yield. I'll edit the solution so that it works in VS2010.

Comment: This solutions is very slick.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to put those `String` values into an array and then use `i` as an index into that array to get one element each iteration.  If you do that though, keep in mind that array indexes start at 0.

You can also use a `For Each` loop to access each element of the array without the need for an index.

Comment: Can you give an example or idea to do it?.

Answer (score 0):

if the default first two string value of your output is `AA`.

You can have a `case`  or `if-else` conditioning statement :
and then set `1 == A` `2 == B`...

the just add or concatenate your default two string and result string of your case.

Comment: I have two textbox sir. example input textbox1 = AAA  and textbox2 = AAD. It will get the range between two textbox input.

Answer (score 0):

in your case to achive goal you may do something like this

```
  Dim S() As String = {"AAA", "AAB", "AAC", "AAD"}

    For Each el In S
        MsgBox(el.ToString)
    Next
```

**FIX FOR PREVIOUS ISSUE**

```
 Dim s1 As String = "AAA"

    Dim s2 As String = "AAZ"

    Dim Last As String = s1.Last
    Dim LastS2 As String = s2.Last
    Dim StartBase As String = s1.Substring(0, 2)
    Dim result As String = String.Empty
    For I As Integer = Asc(s1.Last) To Asc(s2.Last)

        Dim zz As String = StartBase & Chr(I)
        result += zz & vbCrLf
        zz = Nothing
        MsgBox(result)
    Next

   **UPDATE CODE VERSION**

  Dim BARCODEBASE As String = "SBA0021"
    Dim BarCode1 As String = "SBA0021AA1"
    Dim BarCode2 As String = "SBA0021CD9"
    'return AA1
    Dim FirstBarCodeSuffix As String = Replace(BarCode1, BARCODEBASE, "")
    'return CD9
    Dim SecondBarCodeSuffix As String = Replace(BarCode2, BARCODEBASE, "")
    Dim InternalSecondBarCodeSuffix = SecondBarCodeSuffix.Substring(1, 1)

    Dim IsTaskCompleted As Boolean = False

    For First As Integer = Asc(FirstBarCodeSuffix.First) To Asc(SecondBarCodeSuffix)
        If IsTaskCompleted = True Then Exit For
        For Second As Integer = Asc(FirstBarCodeSuffix.First) To Asc(InternalSecondBarCodeSuffix)
            For Third As Integer = 1 To 9
                Dim tmp = Chr(First) & Chr(Second) & Third
                Console.WriteLine(BARCODEBASE & tmp)
                If tmp = SecondBarCodeSuffix Then
                    IsTaskCompleted = True
                End If

            Next
        Next
    Next
    Console.WriteLine("Completed")
    Console.Read()
```

Take a look into this check it and let me know if it can help

Comment: Can You give me guys how can I perform that in two textbox. example textbox 1 = AAA and textbox 2 = AAD output is  AAA, AAB, AAC, AAD

Comment: I'm sorry i misunderstand your question :) i will take a look in few minutes :)

Comment: I have two textbox sir. example input textbox1 = AAA  and textbox2 = AAD. It will get the range between two textbox input.

Comment: checking now it should is exactly what you want

Comment: Your Correct, Your output is showing all the values in messagebox but I want it 1 by 1 showing in my message box just like my code question here. so that i can input every output in my messagebox

Comment: I already done this bit I want Is get between two values not only the last string. just like my serial example, If the user input the starting serial example S30AB to S30B1 it will get the values between them, and every ok in messagebox it will insert to my database.

Comment: Priority is A-z the 0-9

Comment: are those data stored anywhere?if yes you need to store it into a simple list sortit and then filter with linq to object and return.In your case you're predict a future name assuming that there's only few value.Other way you have to checking all the possibile options to create a serial.And it will take too much time :)

Comment: Provide more info please

Comment: Ok let me explain my project. My client wants to scan two bar codes, and they will scan between two data, for example the first input in textbox1 is SBA0021BC and textbox2 is SBA0021CZ, and the range of between this two data will be the output and it be inserted into database so that they can check if there is duplicate entries. barcode always contains 10 characters.

Comment: Assumed that code has 10 characters which are static and which can change only last 2 one letter and 1 digit, both or any other combination ???

Comment: Its in the last four characters because they are scanning maximum of 1000 datas, so i need to create an application that will scan the firstSerial until the last Serial and store it to my database. but my idea is just a select statement which will get between two datas, or any insert method in mysql so that it make it easy?

Comment: Excuse but i missing something ...... Customer choose 2 barcodes as per your example.....you need to find all the items into this range....storeit in database and check if there's a duplicate.....i'm not sure that is the right logic....

Comment: first of all you need to check into a database into this range and get all the records related to it.Then eventually compare this with all the possibile combination (previously created via a function or recursive sub) in order to matching which are not into the db too and then store all the ones that are to be stored.Let me know if it could be a solution

Comment: I know you understand my problem please help, A-Z THEN 0-9 then back to a

Comment: One stuff i used a console to make it faster make all the changes that you need in order to make it fully functional for your need

Comment: Almost done sir but I saw an output SBA0021CB9 then next is SBA0021CC1 it should be SBA0021CCA then SBA0021CCB  then SBA0021CCD .... SBA0021CCZ then back to SBA0021CC1 ... SBA0021CC9   then SBA0021CDA

Comment: i misunderstand sorry i thought that it was CA1 CA2 CA3....instead you need that move from CCA to CCZ then CC1 to CC9

Comment: @Enigmativity has wrote a very simple code i seen it now.Take a look into this it is very very good code.

Comment: This one still doesn't seem right. When Enigmativity's code is very slick, it could be hard to understand for someone that's on the newer side of programming. Check out my updated solution.

Comment: yes it seems the much simply solution @Bob, my code was not the right one coz i misundertand final goal. Your one is a very good one too.

Comment: Confirmed checked your one @bob .....it is very usefull, nice simple code.Great job Bob.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to understand that you are looking for a series using range between 2 textboxes. Here is the code which will take the series and will give the output as required.

```
Dim startingStr As String = Mid(TextBox1.Text, TextBox1.Text.Length, 1)
Dim endStr As String = Mid(TextBox2.Text, TextBox2.Text.Length, 1)

Dim outputstr As String = String.Empty

Dim startNumber As Integer
Dim endNumber As Integer

startNumber = Asc(startingStr)
endNumber = Asc(endStr)

Dim TempStr As String = Mid(TextBox1.Text, 1, TextBox1.Text.Length - 1)

Dim i As Integer
For i = startNumber To endNumber
    outputstr = outputstr + ", " + TempStr + Chr(i)
Next i

MsgBox(outputstr)
```

The First two lines will take out the Last Character of the String in the text box.

So in your case it will get A and D respectively

Then `outputstr` to create the series which we will use in the loop

`StartNumber` and `EndNumber` will be give the Ascii values for the character we fetched.

`TempStr` to Store the string which is left off of the series string like in our case AAA - AAD Tempstr will have AA

then the simple loop to get all the items fixed and show

Comment: This does not work if you enter ABC and ACA into the text boxes.

Comment: Definitely this will give the series for the last characters ... Are u looking for the complete series ABC to ACA

Comment: Yeah I need that, when the char is in the z next is 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 then back to A